# UISearchBar placeholder text - align to centre programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am using `UISearchBar` for search purposes using Objective C. I need the placeholder text of search bar to be aligned to the center of the search bar programatically and when user starts typing, text must be aligned left.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem like yours before. I couldn't find any workaround and after all I just used `UILabel` and `UISearchBarDelegate` methods.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    UISearchBar *srchBar;
    UILabel *customPlaceHolderForSearchBar;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frm = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80);
    srchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:frm];
    srchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:srchBar];

    customPlaceHolderForSearchBar = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frm];
    customPlaceHolderForSearchBar.text = @"PlaceHolder text";
    customPlaceHolderForSearchBar.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    customPlaceHolderForSearchBar.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:customPlaceHolderForSearchBar];


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    customPlaceHolderForSearchBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (searchBar.text.length < 1) {
        customPlaceHolderForSearchBar.hidden = NO;
    }
}

@end
```